# Effect of carbon dioxide impurities on the Haber–Bosch process

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbon-dioxide

The Haber–Bosch process is a highly exothermic reaction that is used to produce ammonia from nitrogen and hydrogen. The nitrogen is typically obtained from the air using a membrane separation process, which results in a product that is 95-99.5% pure. However, there are still small amounts of impurities present, such as oxygen and $\ce{CO2}$.

Oxygen can be easily reduced by incoming hydrogen, so it is not a major concern. However, $\ce{CO2}$ is an inert gas that can inhibit the reaction between nitrogen and hydrogen. The effect of $\ce{CO2}$ on the Haber–Bosch process is not well-understood, but it is thought that even small amounts of $\ce{CO2}$ can have a significant impact on the yield of ammonia.

I am interested in learning more about the effect of $\ce{CO2}$ impurities on the Haber–Bosch process. In particular, I would like to know:

- What is the mechanism by which $\ce{CO2}$ inhibits the reaction between nitrogen and hydrogen?
- How does the concentration of $\ce{CO2}$ affect the yield of ammonia?
- Are there any methods to remove $\ce{CO2}$  from the nitrogen feedstream before the Haber–Bosch process?

I believe that this question is of interest to the chemistry community, and I hope that you will consider answering it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your question is interesting but it will become even better if you add your own search results.

Comment: Refer to Dalton’s law on partial pressures and how this will effect the pressure of the produced gas in a le chat type interaction